# Image data gets corrupted on its way to the browser

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7

I've got an application running under Drupal in a LAMP environment. It delivers images out of a database. On my personal machine (OS X Lion) it is working correctly. On the dev server (Amazon EC2) the exact same code doesn't work. Both servers run PHP 5.3. I've confirmed that the data is getting corrupted between `echo $fileData` and it being received by the browser. Further, I've confirmed that the data is NOT corrupted if it is base64-encoded (I used a script to request the data, decode it, and save it to a file).

On the Drupal side, the code is in a module that creates a menu callback; the callback function echos the file data directly to avoid storing the entire image in memory (I was using PDO::FETCH_BOUND with PDO::PARAM_LOB to create a stream but it's going into a string right now while I'm trying to find the problem; that wasn't it). The menu entry has a custom delivery callback that essentially does nothing. I tried flushing any output buffering on the idea that Drupal might be trying too hard for Unicode support or something, but that didn't help either.

I'm hoping that somebody has an idea of what might be causing my problem. If I haven't been clear enough, I'll post some code; right now it's full of commented-out features so it would take some cleaning up.

**Update 1:**

I put together some example code but it did not exhibit the bug; I may convert the code into a Drupal module to test that code stack. However, I have narrowed down the bug to `echo $fileData`. The code looks something like this:

```
function example_menu() {
  $pages['mpicture/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Picture handler',
    'page callback' => 'example_picture',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'delivery callback' => 'example_deliver_png',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
}

function example_picture($fileID) {
  // Point 1
  example_output_file($fileID);
}

function example_deliver_png($content) {
}

function example_output_file($fileID) {
  $statement = db_select('mfiles', 'f')
    ->fields('f', array('fileType', 'fileSize', 'fileData', 'fileData64', 'lastModified'))
    ->condition('fileID', $fileID, '=')
    ->execute();

  if ($file = $statement->fetchAssoc()) {
    header('Content-Type: ' . $file['fileType']);
    // Point 2
    header('Content-Length: ' . $file['fileSize']);
    echo $file['fileData'];
  }
}
```

This does not work. If I change `Point 2` to this:

```
    // Point 2
    header('Content-Length: ' . $file['fileSize']*4/3);
    echo $file['fileData64'];
```

It works correctly, as long as my client runs a `base64_decode` on the output. However, if I do this:

```
  // Point 1
  ob_start()
  example_output_file($fileID);
  $output = base64_encode(ob_get_clean());
  header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
  echo $output;
```

...it doesn't work with the same `base64_decode`ing client. How could that possibly be?

And yes, I am storing the data twice; in every single test I run it doesn't matter whether I use `$file['fileData']` or `base64_decode($file['fileData64'])` so I don't think it's a database issue.

**Update 2:**

But curiously, this works:

```
  // Point 1
  ob_start()
  example_output_file($fileID);
  $output = base64_encode(trim(ob_get_clean()));
  header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
  echo $output;
```

So, I guess now I try to find where the white space gets printed?

Comment: You could repost your question on [drupal.stackexchange.com](drupal.stackexchange.com).

Comment: At this point I'm pretty sure it's not a Drupal thing because I'm changing all the headers and flushing the output buffers, so there shouldn't be any way for Drupal to mess up the output. Also, every time I've posted something on [drupal.stackexchange.com](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/) it never got any answers or comments; I get the feeling most Drupal people give support on the official support forums. Anyway I only mentioned the Drupal thing to try and cover every possibility.

Comment: If you look at the raw image binary, can you confirm whether there appears to be any html PHP errors it?

Comment: Not sure what browser you are using, but in Google Chrome, can you check and verify that the headers from the image are being sent correctly? Open dev console, network tab, click on the image source and view the header information. Code sample would definitely help too.

Comment: I've inspected the binary response and there are no errors in there. I haven't checked how Chrome receives the headers, but I've checked how cURL receives them, and Chrome displays the page as a broken image unless I comment out the line that sends the header.

Comment: If you're base64 encoding your content, shouldn't you set a content-transfer-encoding header too? I'd be inspecting headers and binary responses with curl. Multiplying your file size by 4/3 seems like a recipe for trouble.

Comment: The base64 encoding is only for testing. I multiply the Content-Length by 4/3 because base64 takes up exactly 4/3 the space of pure binary (64 = 2^6 vs 256 = 2^8). With how I've been testing it actually doesn't matter; when I forget to multiply the Content-Length but the image is valid, it just cuts off the bottom third of the image.

Comment: @meustrus: Err, not exactly, that's approximate not exact, you have to pad to a 3-byte alignment on the source.  That's why you get the `=` or `==` at the end of base64 output.  Read about [base64 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to strangle the intern. I swear it. Not really, it's an expression...but I'm pissed.

The entire problem was because a new file he added had white space at the end of it. A simple "?>\n". This printed white space before every page on the server, including the image handler. The white space made the image corrupt.

I guess the moral here is to never close PHP tags at the end of files, and make damn sure that everyone you work with does the same.

Comment: This post just saved my day. I had the same issue, only I did it to myself by coding something in haste. 15 minutes of coding left 2 spaces after the closing php tag, led to 3 hours of debugging. Grr.

Comment: Just be glad it was only 3 hours and not a whole week. And remember, you don't need to close PHP tags at the end of files. This is perfectly valid and actually within the style of Zend projects (or so I've heard): `<?php echo 'hello world';` (no `?>`)